# How can I create a 3D bounding box around different objects in a point cloud using PCL or Matlab?

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, robotics

I am working with 3D data, and want to create 3d bounding box around possible objects in a point cloud. Or more specifically i want to propose 3D objects in a point clouds using the bounding box. I would like to know how can i do it?

I am working with PCL and Matlab.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First I would look into segmentation techniques in PCL. Once you have the object segmented an axis aligned bounding box is very simple, see pcl::getMinMax3D()

If you would like the bounding box to be oriented, look into Principal Component analysis http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_p_c_a.html